# Synchronizing python requests with opened browser?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

Is this is even possible to synchronize currently opened browser with requests send via python requests library ? I opened some web shop in my tab and I can add some stuff to cart as the offline user there. I want to add the items via POST send from python module. I know that requests create new session beyond the browser. Can I synchronize these 2 things somehow ?

Comment: inspect your browser, get the ```Cookie``` request header, then add same ```Cookie``` request header to your python requests